# Can we automate widgets using Appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-java

We do test our mobile application using Appium. Our app supports widgets in both Android and iOS. Is there a way we can automate these widgets using Appium?

I tried but was not able to inspect the widget elements using Appium.

Comment: To inspect Widgets, the flutter inspector is used

https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector

Launched from Android Studio, contact the developer on how to build the application